# Wiring multiple independent Spring Applications using Maven

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, applicationcontext

My project consists of multiple Spring subprojects:

- Service1
- Service2
- Service3

Every Service has multiple dependencies to other Beans inside, so every Service has an applicationContext.xml wiring the Service together.

I made every subproject an standalone maven build and i thought i can create a AllServicesTogether Application to wire those Service{1..3} together.

This works by adding maven dependencies to those Services.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject-service{1..3}</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

But inside the AllServicesTogether Application, all wiring of the SubServices is lost. I guess Subservices aren't compiled with the Subservice ApplicationContext, but use the AllServicesTogether ApplicationContext.

The Idea is to encapsulate all wiring of SubSerivces and simply wire the AllServicesTogether by using:

```
<beans ..>
    <bean class="org.myproject.service1.Service1"/>
    <bean class="org.myproject.service1.Service2"/>
    <bean class="org.myproject.service1.Service3"/>
</beans>
```

I created those subprojects from the bigger project spending hours on it.
Is it possible to use this wiring method or do i need to include the context.xml's from all those Services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the context.xml's from those services.  This is best done using 'import' in your AllServicesTogether-context.xml:

```
<import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/service1-context.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/service2-context.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/service3-context.xml" />
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This works only if i can tell the services explicitly, but it works. I need this to work for a big amount of files and try to using pattern matching, please see also my more detailed approach: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523945/spring-applicationcontext-with-multiple-xml-files-from-jar)

Answer (score 1):

use classpath*:/META-INF/spring/*-context.xml

References：

1. [Spring application context loading tricks](http://www.gridshore.nl/2008/05/13/spring-application-context-loading-tricks/)
2. [Spring ApplicationContext with multiple XML Files from Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523945/1190388)