# Spring ApplicationContext with multiple XML Files from Jar

Tags: java, spring, classpath, classloader, applicationcontext

I need to create a ApplicationContext with the "main" applicationContext-a.xml from the current Maven build. The other one wires classes from another maven build and is preset in the jar included by a Maven Dependency.

**Here the idea:**

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( new String[] {
                "classpath*:applicationContext-*.xml"});
```

This should load applicationContext-a.xml from the Classpath because it's in the same Project. *This works.*

Then applicationContext-b.xml should be loaded from the dependency-jar. 
*This doesn't work.*

Note that

```
"classpath*:applicationContext-*.xml"
```

Only matches the XMLs inside the direct classpath, nothing inside the jar.

**What i found out:**

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( new String[] {
                "classpath*:applicationContext-*.xml", "classpath*:applicationContext-b.xml"});
```

This works, but only if i explicitly can tell the filename of the xml inside the jar: applicationContext-b.xml

I also need this to work for Integration Tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"**/applicationContext*.xml"})
public class TestClass { ... }
```

The best idea might be a custom loader?
There have to be a way to get this Pattern work...

There was a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303242/loading-spring-application-context-files-that-are-inside-a-jar-in-classpath) some time ago, which works the other way round: It only gets the applicationContext.xml from the jar. If there's anotherone inside the classpath it only matches on this file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `classpath*:` I think has a limitation doesn't work for files under the root folder. Try moving the files under a folder - something like `spring/application-a.xml` and `spring/application-b.xml`.  Then you can have a path `classpath*:/spring/application-*.xml`.

Comment: That's simply crazy, it works if the xml files are in a subdirectory like 'spring' inside the jars. Thank you very much