# I want to use spring context-xml of Maven Dendenpent Project

Tags: xml, spring, maven

I have two projects and each project has Spring XML files in their respective resources folder.

But one project is referenced by the other projects like importing jar.

How can I use XML in jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `classpath*:/application-context.xml`  - replace `application-context.xml` with your filename.

If your Spring XML file is named applicaiton-context.xml move it under a folder spring in both the projects. You can then create a context with both XML files like this

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClasspathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/spring/application-context.xml")
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean. Can you make a example for that?

Comment: I have updated the answer based on guessing what your problem is. If it doesn't answer your question please consider editing your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xml from the jar and the xml from your project:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( new String[] {
                "classpath*:spring/applicationContext-*.xml"});
```

See my [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523945/spring-applicationcontext-with-multiple-xml-files-from-jar) and [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519622/wiring-multiple-independent-spring-applications-using-maven) here.